# Django login stops working randomly

Tags: django, https, nginx, gevent, gunicorn

Env:

- Django 1.42
- Nginx
- Gunicorn + gevent
- HTTPS

Session storage is default

For some reason login stops working without any reason for some clients on different OS/browsers. Auth is passing, but after redirect user.is_authenticated is False again. 
I think, the problem is unrelated to client.

Any ideas why?

Comment: can you verify the cookies in the clients are there?

Comment: unfortunately I dont have an access to that machines, on my side it always works perfectly. Is it possible that HTTPS certificate without 'intermediate' part is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Django user sessions are getting messed up somehow. Try switching your [session engine](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-SESSION_ENGINE) and make sure your session engine is not running off of a [dummy caching backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development). If it is running off of a caching engine, make sure your cache isn't being restarted/flushed somehow. Lastly, try using a [cookie session backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions).